# MongoDB/Mongoose $inc subdocument does not modify anything

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I am trying to update a subdocument inside of an array.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7a017e0aa5311d9c75c86b"),
    "campaignId" : "5a7a017e0aa5311d9c75c86b",
    "subCampaigns" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a7a0eee6849f507d0499a18"),
            "name" : "test5",
            "campaignId" : ObjectId("5a7a017e0aa5311d9c75c86b"),
            "subCampaignId" : "1aKysewspn6CqNGVkv6pyL"
        }
        {
            "name" : "test8",
            "amountRaised" : 20.0,
            "campaignId" : ObjectId("5a7a017e0aa5311d9c75c86b"),
            "subCampaignId" : "5a7a153fe035de396c6f5b3c",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a7a153fe035de396c6f5b3c")
        }
    ],
    "name" : "test8",
    "__v" : 12,
    "totalDonated" : 110.0
}
```

When I run:

```
db.getCollection('campaigns').update({"_id": ObjectId("5a7a017e0aa5311d9c75c86b"), "subCampaigns.subCampaignId":"5a7a153fe035de396c6f5b3c"}, {$inc: {"subCampaigns.$.amountRaised": 10}})
```

In the mongo console it updates the sub document fine. But when I run this in my Mongoose code:

```
this.campaignModel.update(
          { campaignId: '5a7a017e0aa5311d9c75c86b', 'subCampaigns.subCampaignId': '5a7a153fe035de396c6f5b3c' },
          { $inc: { 'subCampaigns.$.amountRaised': 10}},
          (err: any, subResult: any) => {...
```

The sub document does not have its amountRaised field incremented. From what I can tell they should be identical calls?

If I run an inc at the level higher:

```
this.campaignModel.findOneAndUpdate(
                {campaignId: object.campaignId},
                {$inc: {totalDonated: donationAmount}},
                () => {...
```

It works fine, so this must have something to do with the sub document?
I have been playing around with multiple mongoose calls for most of the day but cannot seem to get it to update correctly.

Comment: campaignId: '**5**a7a017e0aa5311d9c75c86b' is this a typo ?

Comment: @Veeram yes it was but just on this post as before I had object.campaignId and object.subCampaignId in there instead of hardcoded values, just put the actualy values in there call for this post. I just double checked and it still does not update it correctly just referencing the variables. This is what is in the variable object right now:   campaignId: '5a7a017e0aa5311d9c75c86b',
  subCampaignId: '5a7a153fe035de396c6f5b3c',